# `///<reference` path to node_modules is not found?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webstorm, node-modules

I'm facing a weird issue with my angular project ( via WebStorm).

I've installed a package called `tns-core-modules`.And  within  that folder (under `node_modules/tns-core-modules`) [there is a `d.ts` file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvZ0x.jpg):

**reference.d.ts**

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts" />
```

The referenced files DOES exist :

[image]

**Question**

If so - why do I see that webstorm doesn't find those references ?

[image]

[*ts.config file*](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ea539d865a519855f7a27d4bcf574bc4)

Node ver : v8.9.1
npm ver : 5.5.1

EDIT

[Looking at the error itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lahFb.jpg)  , and  [Webstorm's error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIDzz.jpg)  :

> TS6053: File
>   'c:/NS/pre-dev/NS-developmentGroceriesV2/node_modules/tns-core-modules/node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.t.s'
>   not found

This is the *wrong* path to the file. The right path is :

> C:/NS/pre-dev/NS-DevelopmentGroceriesV2/node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts

In other words : the yellow part is wrong :

[image]

How can I make it see the right path location ?

Comment: @Siggy  I **also** have a `reference.d.ts` in the root folder. and to tell you the truth , when I put those references there - I _don't_ see any errors. But my problem is that I've installed a package and that package has its own `reference.d.ts` and at that file I see the errors. Does it mean  that on every package with reference.d.t.s - I must copy its content to the root `reference.d.ts` ?

Comment: you have the `reference.d.ts` located in `c:/NS/pre-dev/NS-developmentGroceriesV2/node_modules/tns-core-modules`, right? As relative paths (starting with `./`) are resolved relative to current file, `"./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts"` resolves to `"c:/NS/pre-dev/NS-developmentGroceriesV2/node_modules/tns-core-modules/node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts`. If the file can't be found by this path, errors will be shown by Typescript compiler

Comment: @lena so the refernce.d.ts shouldn't  have been there (tns-core-modules) at first place right? It should've been in the root. Right?

Comment: right - it should either be placed in root or the path in `///<reference>` comment changed